# MySQL statement performance and optimisation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need your advice on the best way to traverse through and return values from a database (as shown below). The structure of the database is set by another application.

How the system currently returns the value of a user with ID=6 in this case:

Look for item instance and item module (1 and training) and return the row ID. Using this row ID, look for the corresponding itemid and userid in table 2.

grade_grades

[image: Table1]

grade_items

[image: Table2]

Current SQL / functions :

function 1 { SELECT ID FROM grade_items WHERE itemmodule = 'training' and iteminstance = '1' } (returns ID)

function 2 { using returned ID, run the following: SELECT * FROM grade_grades WHERE itemid = '4' AND userid = '6'} (returns finalgrade)

Is there an easier way of getting all of this in one MYSQL statement rather than running two queries? (The reason I am asking is because there is a potential each of these queries will run from 100 to 10000 times - depending on the number of users in the list. Currently - the server grinds to a halt for about 15 minutes if I run the query for all records (without pagenation to calculate totals)

Comment: you can `join` on a common column. is there any?

Comment: do you have proper indexes in database?

Answer (score 1):

Just join them together :

```
SELECT g.*
FROM grade_items g
JOIN grade_grades g2
 ON(g2.id = g.itemid)
WHERE g2.itemmodule = 'training' and g2.iteminstance = '1'
```

Or alternatively , use `IN()` :

```
SELECT g.*
FROM grade_items g
WHERE g.itemid IN(SELECT g2.id FROM grade_grades  g2
                  WHERE g2.itemmodule = 'training'
                    and g2.iteminstance = '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **JOIN**  which is combine rows from two or more tables

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM grade_grades 
 JOIN grade_items ON grade_grades.id = grade_items.itemid
 WHERE itemid = 4
```